# getting an array from a parentView in sproutcore

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

```
App.MapView = App.ChartView.extend({
  data: undefined,
  dataLoaded: NO,
  markersArray: undefined,

  finishloadingdata: function (rawdata) {
    var latitude, longitude;
    var array = new Array();
    $(rawdata).find("Book").each(function () {
      $(this).find("Location");
      latitude = $(this).find("Latitude").text();
      longitude = $(this).find("Longitude").text();

      array.push(new Array(latitude, longitude));
    });
    this.set('markersArray', array);
    this.set('data', rawdata);
    this.set('dataLoaded', YES);
  },

  optionsView: SC.View.extend({
    layout: {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 50
    },
    map: null,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.48, 7.9),
    zoom: 14,
    array: this.get('markersArray'),
    didCreateMap: null,
    render: function (ctx, first) {
      if (first) {
        ctx.push('<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;"></div>');
      }
    },
    didCreateLayer: function () {
      this.invokeLast('_createMap');
    },

    _createMap: function () {
      if (this._map) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(this._map, 'resize');
      } else {
        var center = this.get('center');

        var opts = {
          zoom: this.get('zoom'),
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var div = this.$('div')[0];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(div, opts);

        this._map = map;
        this.set('map', map);

        //i want to make an array of markers

        if (this.didCreateMap) this.didCreateMap(map);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.48, 7.9),
          map: map
        });
      }
    }
```

The MapView is a view that extends ChartView, i'm overriding the optionsView to make it display a google map. it works just fine, i just want to put markers on that map with the coordinates retrieved from an xml file. I'm getting the array just fine.
My problem is when i want to give the optionsView the value of that array it's giving me the error:  **Object [object Window] has no method 'get'**.

How can i give the array property of the optionsView the value of markersArray so i can use it to put the markers on my map.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
array: this.get('markersArray')
```

you probably want to do

```
arrayBinding: 'parentView.markersArray'
```

This uses SproutCore's [bindings](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Binding.html) feature and will ensure that the `array` property always points to the parent view's `markersArray` property. However, you may also need to specify that `optionsView` is a child of the parent by adding the following to the top of the chart view:

```
App.MapView = App.ChartView.extend({
  childViews: ['optionsView'],
  ...
```

Hope this helps! If you have any additional questions about this issue, please add a comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: @Elie No problem! Glad to be of service :-)